# zero value cpu_time and duration in sql_statement_completed extended event

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, extended-events

On Microsoft SQL Server 2014 (SP2-CU3) (KB3204388) - 12.0.5538.0 (X64) 
   Enterprise Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.1  
            (Build 7601: Service Pack 1) (Hypervisor)

almost all events have a zero value in **cpu_time** and **duration** fields (in 1/1000000 second) in **sql_statement_completed** extended event. Yet statement are not so simple, for example :

```
UPDATE <table> SET <field> = Value, etc...
FROM (SELECT <fields> WHERE <condition>) AS t1
WHERE <condition>
```

And sporadically some have thousands values like 15000 or 16000, with same kind of statement...

How is it possible that it take 0 **microsecond** to do anything ? Or is it a bug/limitation in extended events ?

EDIT :

here is the XE create statement :

```
CREATE EVENT SESSION [XE_sql_statement_completed] ON SERVER
ADD EVENT sqlserver.sql_statement_completed(
    SET collect_statement=(0)
    ACTION(package0.collect_current_thread_id,
        package0.event_sequence,sqlserver.client_app_name,
        sqlserver.client_hostname,sqlserver.client_pid,sqlserver.database_name,
        sqlserver.nt_username,sqlserver.server_principal_name,
        sqlserver.session_id,sqlserver.session_nt_username,
        sqlserver.sql_text,sqlserver.username))
ADD TARGET package0.histogram(
                 SET filtering_event_name=N'sqlserver.sql_statement_completed',
                    source=N'sqlserver.database_name'),
ADD TARGET package0.ring_buffer(SET max_events_limit=(400))
WITH  (MAX_MEMORY=4096 KB,EVENT_RETENTION_MODE=NO_EVENT_LOSS,
MAX_DISPATCH_LATENCY=3 SECONDS, MAX_EVENT_SIZE=0 KB,
MEMORY_PARTITION_MODE=NONE,TRACK_CAUSALITY=OFF,STARTUP_STATE=OFF)
```

So I fetch the data in the ring buffer

Comment: What's your XE session definition, and how are you looking at the data? Query or GUI?

Comment: some update? The only explanation I see to this is that ins most of time, commands are spending less than 1 microseconds, and running in nanoseconds...